# Android Webview fail load mixed page

Tags: android, webview

In my android app i have used webview to load https url. Page contains mixed content (secure and unsecure). I receive `onReceivedError()` with **net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT** statement.When i try connect to server by this url in a chrome, establishing connection take a lot of time (approximately 5 minutes) but succeeded.

How i can resolve this problem?
Or
**How i can increase connection time of WebView?**
`function setMixedContentMode( WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW )` I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
 WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
 wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

 @Override
 public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        // do your stuff here
       }
});
```

Comment: @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, android.webkit.SslErrorHandler handler, android.net.http.SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
    };

Comment: Prashant Mishra what do you mean? i know this method and use it. onReceivedSslError() callback do not called